Issues with Babel version and Webpack errors when running React app in Docker
I'm working on a React project, and I initially encountered the following error when starting the app:
Requires Babel "^7.16.0", was loaded with "7.12.3".
I updated my package.json based on a suggestion I found here, but now I'm encountering new errors. My setup includes Docker Desktop, and I'm unable to create containers successfully. After running the app, it now shows:
webpack compiled with 10 errors and 1 warning.
The problem is that I can only use the Dockerfile from a year ago and not the image from a year ago. The process that I currently always run through when I make a change is that I create an image for the frontend and backend from the Docker files and these images then start as containers within the Docker environment.
However, when I recreate the images, the packages are obtained and compiled from the package sources according to the package.json. As there have of course been changes to the packages in the last few months, I do not get the version from a few months ago loaded into my image, but the latest version.
{
  "name": "carbon-tutorial",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "repository": "git@github.com:carbon-design-system/carbon-tutorial.git",
  "bugs": "https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-tutorial/issues",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "ci-check": "yarn format:diff",
    "clean": "yarn cache clean && yarn install",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,md,scss}\"",
    "format:diff": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{js,md,scss}\"",
    "format:staged": "prettier --write",
    "start-api": "cd api && venv/Scripts/flask run --no-debugger",
    "build-api": "cd api && python -m venv venv && venv/Scripts/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt && cd..",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@carbon/charts": "^1.22.0",
    "@carbon/charts-react": "^1.22.0",
    "@carbon/icons-react": "^11.48.0",
    "@carbon/upgrade": "^11.17.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "@types/carbon-components-react": "^7.55.1",
    "carbon-components": "^10.58.0",
    "carbon-components-react": "^8.66.0",
    "carbon-icons": "^7.0.7",
    "d3": "^7.9.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "react": "^18.3.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "react-keep-alive": "^2.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "7.5.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "7.5.0",
    "husky": "1.3.1",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "sass": "1.29.0",
    "wait-for-expect": "3.0.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "*"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001632",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "10.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -e $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional"
    ]
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "yarn format:staged",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.{scss,css}": [
      "yarn format:staged",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.md": [
      "yarn format:staged",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "prettier": {
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  },
  "proxy": "http://backend:5000"
}


# pull official base image
FROM node:22.9.0-alpine3.19

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]


I have tried various solutions to no avail. As a beginner, I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

It's completely impossible to help without seeing what the actual compilation errors are. You can also try building with the environment variable BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain to see more output.
